# Rails/Bootstrap. Using .each falling to have a new Thumbnail next to the one before horizontally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Every cycle I get the new Thumbnail BUT under the previous one.  Any suggestions how to solve that?  How in each cycle add the new Thumbnail horizontally next to the previous one, until the space is fill and then move to the next line?  Thanks.

[From TO Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5zi8.jpg)

CODE

```
 <% @employees.each do |em| %>
    <div class="listTumbnail">
        <% if em.user.imagepath %>
            <div class = "user-image">
                <img src="<%= em.user.imagepath%>" class="listimg">
            </div>
        <% else %>
            <div>
                <%= image_tag("icons/desconocido.jpg", :alt => "not found", :class => "listimg") %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <% end %>

.user-image {
  float: none;
  padding-top: 127px;
  margin-left: 193px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: #000;
  border-left-width: 1px;
}

.listimg {
  display: block;
  max-width:80px;
  max-height:100px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.listTumbnail {
    border: 2px solid #95989A;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #000;
    height: 140px;
    width: 110px;
    margin: 5px;
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide an image or something of the behavior and  amore detailed explanation of what you want it to actually do?

Comment: Hi, I added a From to picture.. hopes it clarifies.  Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the CSS/stylesheet you are using for this code?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
.listThumbnail {
  display: block;
}

.user-image {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

If for some reason you don't have a css file in your project, here's one basic way to add one:

Create a file named `my_styles.css` (or whatever you want to name it) & add the above css examples there.

Add the following link in the `<head>` of your `application.html.erb` file:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_styles.css">`

This allows your html file to work with your css file/stylesheet.

Comment: Hi Brandon,  Thank you for your answer.  It didn't work:  This is the CSS I have: 
.user-image {
  float: none;
  padding-top: 127px;
  margin-left: 193px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: #000;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

Comment: .listTumbnail {
    border: 2px solid #95989A;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #000;
    height: 140px;
    width: 110px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
  }

Comment: .listimg {
  display: block;
  max-width:80px;
  max-height:100px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

Comment: Pretty sure that has to do with your padding & margin properties set for `.user-image`.  Try changing your css to: `.user-image {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: #000;
  border-left-width: 1px; 
}` and then see how you want to re-adjust any padding/margins/etc.  You still need to keep the `display: block` for `.listThumbnail`.

Comment: btw.  An example of what I think you are trying to do (minus the ruby code): https://jsfiddle.net/ypr5trga/

Comment: THanks.. that is exactly what I want to do!  While that work with a .each statement?

Comment: Yes, it will work the same.  You will probably also want to add a class to the second image and give it similar styling...like this: `<% else %>
            <div class="else-image">
                <%= image_tag("icons/desconocido.jpg", :alt => "not found", :class => "listimg") %>
            </div>
        <% end %>`

Comment: Please upvote my answer if it was helpful.  Good luck!